# Computer that can't upgrade beyond Windows 1803 - safe to use until when?

Tags: windows, operating-systems, driver

I have an old computer that can't (at least according to Windows Update) upgrade beyond Windows 1803. (Probably due to the manufacturer not releasing updates to drivers.) Until when will it be safe to use?

This seems a little strange to me. In the past, Windows versions had a pretty long life. At least as far as security updates were concerned. It seems as if now with Windows 10, computers have a *much* shorter life expectancy due to lack of drivers combined with Microsoft treating the updates as something *everyone* is expected to do, though in reality it's not possible. Am I missing something here?

Comment: This is something subjective. MS-DOS is still safe to use if you take what is needed for that into consideration. As a general note, Windows 7 end support next year and will get security patches for 2 more years. An estimation is much more complex for a specific version of Windows 10. It may be obsolete tomorrow due to high risk breaches or good for years.